# "No values found" for search refiners SharePoint 2013 On premises

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, refiner

I am trying to create new search refiner in SP2013 on-premises environment.We are referring  [MSDN article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/10/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/) for refiner creation.

When we try to add the refiner to the refinement web part we get a message

> " No values found "

can anyone help me if we are missing any step here?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I would use search to find out first whether there is item contains the managed property. Maybe the managed property is correct, just no one put value in it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things that often tricked me when working with refiner:

1: The preview where it finds example items based on your refiner uses the searchword currently in the search bar. So if you haven't entered anything it will show up empty.

2: The managed property might not contain any items even though it should. Make sure to test if there could be any other managed property that could contain the values you are seeking.